# How to include boost math library using CMake

Tags: c++, boost, cmake

I am trying to include the Math library from Boost into my CMake C++ project, however the compiler returns an error when it's linking libraries.

This is my `CMakeLists.txt`

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.24)
project(ImageProcessor)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)

find_package(OpenCV REQUIRED)
find_package(Boost REQUIRED)
include_directories(${OpenCV_INCLUDE_DIRS})

add_executable(ImageProcessor main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(ImageProcessor ${OpenCV_LIBS} Boost::boost)
```

Edit:
This is the error which I get at build:

```
/usr/bin/ld: CMakeFiles/ImageProcessor.dir/main.cpp.o: undefined reference to symbol '_ZN3tbb6detail2r114execution_slotEPKNS0_2d114execution_dataE'
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/libtbb.so.12: error adding symbols: DSO missing from command line
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Comment: Are you sure you have to link to boost::math ? Most of the math functions are header only. Whats the error you have at link ?

Comment: I'm trying to use the `math::statistics::simple_ordinary_least_squares_with_R_squared` function, I've updated my question so that it includes the compilation error.

Comment: @Robomaze: If you only need math, use the standalone:  https://github.com/boostorg/math/releases/tag/boost-1.80.0

Answer (score 3):

Boost is split into multiple CMake targets, `Boost::boost` is the header only version.

You have to explicitly link to the precompiled components of boost you want to use. In this case, you must also link again `Boost::math`. It might also be required to search for the component via `find_package(Boost REQUIRED COMPONENTS math)`